# Integer arithmetic in equals expression

Tags: java, integer, unboxing

I know the first expression evaluates to false because these are two distinct ***Integer*** objects.

I'm not sure why the second expression evaluates to true.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
   System.out.println(new Integer(1000)==new Integer(1000)); // false       
   System.out.println(new Integer(1000)==new Integer(1000)+new Integer(0)); // true
}
```

I suspect that the second expression evaluates to true because the right hand side first gets unboxed to an ***int*** and then gets compared to the left side. Is that true and if so, is this the defined behavior?

Comment: Yes, `new Integer(1000)+new Integer(0)` needs to be unboxed for using the + operator. The result will be an `int` and the comparison then will need to unbox the left hand side as well.

Comment: BTW `Integer.valueOf(1000)` would be correct coding style, even if it normally does not chache the Integer.

Answer (score 0):

Because new Integer(1000)+new Integer(0) return 1000 value. So java compare values of Integer. 1000==1000 is equals true. Bu first output is false because int this why java compare references of objects.